# Extract part of file name using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I get about 200 files everyday that need to be processed.
I need to extract the part of the file name.
For Example, I receive the files with the following naming convention:

```
X12345678 - NAME - DocumentType.pdf
```

I need a PowerShell script to extract the `'X12345678'` part of the file name to process it further.

Can you please help me with this.

Comment: Can you also provide something which you have tried. SO is not a free code writing site.

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. [SO] isn't a free script writing service. Own research and code attempts are expected. [Edit] the question to include **your** code in a [mcve]. You are possibly looking for The `-split` operator. See `Get-Help about_split` --> `("X12345678 - NAME - DocumentType.pdf" -split ' - ')[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple RegEx.  Given a filename as per your example, here is the general idea:

```
# Check the filename
if("X12345678 - NAME - DocumentType.pdf" -match "^(?<code>\w\d+) -.*$")
{
    # Get the code
    $fileCode = $matches.code

    # Do something with the code
    "Filename is valid: $fileCode"
}
else
{
    "Filename is not in required format"
}
```